# find unique items in a set of arrays and remove non-uniques from arrays found

Tags: javascript

Givven an object with **Key** as an Array (of position) and **Value** as an Array as well:

```
// Example Object
0,2 : [6, 8, 9]
0,3 : [1, 6, 8]
0,4 : [6, 8]
0,5 : [6, 8]
0,6 : [4, 5, 8, 9]
0,7 : [5, 8]
0,8 : [4, 5, 7, 9]
```

(it was created like this:

```
x = {};
x[[0,2]] = [6, 8, 9];
x[[0,3]] = [1, 6, 8];
...
```

Now, I want to narrow down my object to this, by checking if any number in an Array **appears only inside this array**, and not in others value's arrays, then eliminating all the other numbers inside the specific array which holds the unique number.
(Rule: no duplicated inside a given array, so no need to check that):

```
// Result Object
0,2 : [6, 8, 9]
0,3 : [1]
0,4 : [6, 8]
0,5 : [6, 8]
0,6 : [4, 5, 8, 9]  // now 4 becomes also a "loner"
0,7 : [5, 8]
0,8 : [7]
```

so here in Key [0,3] the Value's array was narrowed down to just [1] because 1 is a unique number not showing up in the other array.

I'm having trouble thinking of an efficient pattern for this...

Comment: So like the compliment of the intersection of the two sets (if you think of the arrays as sets)?

Comment: I've carefully read this 4 times and still can't understand the problem.

Comment: yes it's a complicated problem a bit. I don't know exactly how to implement a solution to change the given Object to match the result needed...still not clear?

Comment: If we can't understand it, there's no way to answer it ;)

Comment: as you can see, there is an Example Object and a Result Object, and the answer would be the way to get from the example state to the result state. the key here is to eliminate all the numbers in a Value's Array, if a number inside the array is unique across all the other Value's Arrays...

Comment: @vsync: I think you really might have to start from scratch here. You have a clear problem but one that is poorly defined as no-one can understand the process that is applied to get from the example state to the result state.

Comment: So, is it just because `1` and `7` both occur only once, and therefore everything else is removed from their array?

Comment: @Bryan - Yes, exactly :) it was a bit difficult to describe but i thought it would be understood from the Result needed..

Comment: maybe it would be clearer if I say this is for a Soduko game i'm building, and the object is Cells positions and the possibilities inside them, an an Array of numbers

Comment: @vsync, my problem in understanding your question is looking at `0,4` and `0,5` is `0,5` not empty because there is no difference in teh array beforehand?  I think your result object is all kinds of wrong.

Comment: @vol7ron: in both [0,4] & [0,5] there are numbers that appear in other arrays as well, therefor nothing special about them, and should not be modified. my result is implacable. the way to achieve it is just tricky.

Comment: @vsync: your example doesn't make sense. If in `0,3` you got rid of 6 and 8, why would you not in `0,4` and `0,5`? When I think about your question, the result in my head is looking like amit_g's answer, where you just keep the numbers in the first encountered property, having the properties sorted alpha-numerically.

Comment: @vol7ron: this is for a Sudoku games. you cross out possibilities for cells which have only 1 unique number which isn't found in other cells. that means, that if in cell [0,3] there was number '1', and no in any of the others, so we cross out all the other possibilities, inside that cell, because clearly only '1' can be there.

Comment: @vsync: ahh, you should have said it was for Sudoku.  Remember that Sudoku has both horizontal and vertical restrictions. Also, there are 9 squares, not 7.  So based on your question, you're just looking at finding `unique` numbers of the entire set, and removing the non-unique numbers in the element the unique number is found.

Comment: @vol7ron: yes I said it was for Sudoku in the comments above this. the example has only 7 cells, because it's just an example so it doesn't matter, and every BOX in the game (that consists of 9 cells) has some pre-filled cells, so there is almost never 9 cells with possibilities set in them.

Comment: @vsync: your only mention of Sudoku was the comment to me, before the one that I said you should have mentioned it was Sudoku [in your post].

Comment: @vsync: see if my solution is what you're trying to get, before we optimize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea here it that i go through every number in every array, and check it against
a Bucket (string) which holds all the numbers from all the arrays, joined. if the first index of the current `x[key][i]` in the bucket is the SAME as the last index, it means this number is unique and, thus it's holding array is reset to hold that number alone.

```
var x = {};  // object

x[[0,0]] = [6, 8, 9];
x[[0,1]] = [1, 6, 8];
x[[0,2]] = [6, 8];
x[[0,3]] = [6, 8];
x[[0,4]] = [4, 5, 8, 9];
x[[0,5]] = [5, 8];
x[[0,6]] = [4, 5, 7, 9];

function findUniquePosibilites(x){
    var bucket = "";
    for(var key in x)
        bucket += x[key].join("");

    for(var key in x)
        for (var i = x[key].length; i--; ){
            var num = x[key][i];
            if( bucket.indexOf(num) ==  bucket.lastIndexOf(num) ){
                x[key] = [num];
                break;
            };
        }
}

findUniquePosibilites(x);
console.dir( x );

/*
0,0 : [6, 8, 9] 
0,1 : [1]
0,2 : [6, 8]
0,3 : [6, 8]    
0,4 : [4, 5, 8, 9]  
0,5 : [5, 8]    
0,6 : [7]
*/
```

Comment: function calls are one of the most least efficient solutions, if looking for performance, I'd stay away from that.

Comment: I am more looking for a pretty solution which consist of as few code lined as possible, but would be still understandable (not compressed or anything)

Comment: I have perfected my code, and I think now it's the best solution of all, as it is fast and I think as small as it can get almost

Comment: I don't think it's any faster than mine and mine is still not optimized (though you won't really see a difference), but yes using jQuery, it is condensed.  To that argument, if you included the jQuery methods in your code, you'll notice it is considerably larger and more confusing :) Also, I don't think indexOf is cross-browser, at least it wasn't at one time, which is why I did not use it; that would replace one of my loops.  I say go with whatever is easier for you to understand down the road.

Comment: Also, be aware, in order to terminate your recursion, you'll have to make sure the original object was modified in some way.  This can be done using a flag (as I have done) or comparing the initial object to the returned object, which will double your memory and increase processing time.  That may also be why mine appears more cluttered.  Regardless, yours works and I'm glad you found a solution

Comment: I only used the $merge, but i can just use Array.Push as well thus eliminating the need to jQuery. I use the latest javascript version 1.8.5 which utilize ECMAScript 5. I don't care for browsers not supporting it. it's not my problem :) Chrome and FF4 supports it.

Comment: I have removed jQuery's merge and made a merging of my own, to keep it clean. and 'indexOf' on Array is from javascript 1.6

Comment: Right, I think it was ie6 and older FFs that don't support it, which is why mozilla had a user-include prototype available on their site. -- The **problem** your code will come across is if an element has more than one unique value.  Example, put a `3` in your "0,6".  Your method will eventually end up with `7`, whereas mine will contain `3,7`.  That is because I'm not replacing the array if a unique is found, I'm adding to it, or more accurately, I'm only removing non-uniques from the current list.

Comment: yes, but we are talking about Sudoku here, so such situation will not occur, there can't be 2 uniques in the same cell, impossible.

Comment: @vsync: that all depends on when the call is made and how you structure your program.  If the options are defined by user input, then it could be possible (example: some solvers allow users to pen in what the options could be).  If you're starting from elements having all options `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9`, then it's less likely to occur.

Comment: Before you select your code as an answer, I would [check the benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/unique-array) between ours.  Also, notice that yours does not work in IE7, as it can't find the method `concat`

Comment: I wonder why does your method has such high timing fluctuation

Comment: @vsync: I was wrong, it wasn't `concat`, it's the `indexOf` that IE7 can't handle, which is something I stated in an earlier comment.  -- BTW, my method has lower timing, the number is demonstrating # ops/sec, thus, my code can run more times than yours; hence, it's faster.  There are several reasons that could be.  For one, you're using concat/indexOf, which might not be efficient; second, my method minimizes the amount of look ups, by only caching the position that has a unique number.  Another reason could be the difference in [ternary vs if/else](http://jsperf.com/ternary-if-else)

Comment: i don't get it. i see that my method has lower timing then yours, It manages to do a lot more operations per second..

Comment: No, the measurement is in `ops/sec`, so the higher the better.  Tests show that your method is slower in FF3 and does not work at all in IE7.  Newer versions of either may have optimized the array functions, I'll have to check from another computer to see if so.  It's because browsers change the optimizations of the interpreter from version to version, that micro-optimization is discouraged.  However, your solution isn't just an optimization problem, it simply doesn't work in IE7, which still has a decent percent (5.3%) of all browsers.

Comment: @vol7ron - I have optimized my method even more optimized it. now it supports all browsers and 200% faster in Firefox and 100% faster in Chrome. http://jsperf.com/unique-array/2

Comment: even the un-optimized one is faster than yours, where did you see yours was faster?

Comment: ok, yet again, even MORE optimization. now it is close to optimum! check the benchmarks, done in 4 different browsers. speed gain is vast

Comment: Yes, perhaps it was the machine, which was running AMD and had a bunch of security software over top.  These newer browsers on this lightweight box shows your methods to be faster.  Of course, I'm not sure your new one would work if you went to a larger array (greater than 3x3).  Again, I didn't micro-optimize mine either, though I'm not sure it can be optimized much past yours.

Comment: I like your revised index of, but I like the potential flexibility of building the unique array list (my last one : http://jsperf.com/unique-array/6), even if it's a tad slower.  It's essentially the same thing as my solution above, but it doesn't worry if a block has multiple uniques (condition you later made).  -- I've also noticed some weird conditions in these new browsers, where reverse-while loops don't seem to have the impact they once did.

Comment: my method will work on grids larger than 3x3 by changing: `bucket += x[key].join(",") + ","` so when it's comma separated the numbers won't get mixed.

Comment: the test environment is not sterile, you should have put the creating of the main object outside of the tests, and also for your tests you changed the initial Object with the Keys to an Array or Arrays, so that means the tests cannot be compared anymore between them

Comment: I have "changed" my method in your test to use the same 2D array you are starting with, and it made it twice as fast...magic :)

Comment: @vsync: `1:` your method is stripping commas, which means your indexOf method is only accurate for single digits values [0-9], unless you wish to use alpha-numeric values.  `2:` My test is sterile. I created two separate objects (1 obj/1 multidimensional array) outside of the test, but jsPerf acted weird - I suspect the underlying Java/Browser is not resetting it at each test.  Besides, you'd want to evaluate the complete difference between the codes, including declaration/initialization of the objects. `3:` Iterating arrays is much faster than objects, and objects contain native properties

Comment: i ran some tests and it doesn't really matter if I use commas or not, the speed difference is minor. but for my Sudoku needs I would try to golf my code to suit it just right. I will very soon release my game, and share it here. i'm not only down to the point of grading the boards I generate, and thats a tricky thing

Comment: Again, if your board went to something larger than 3x3 (eg 4x4), the numbers would be 1-16, which means your string could look something like `341324116113245823452` and you'd have no way of knowing what was a 1,3 and what was a 13 w/o a delimited; but reiterating what I said, you could use alphanumeric: `3413241b61d245823452`

Comment: i know. if I want a board larger than that I would have used the comma separator, which bears almost no meaning on performance anyway. I just choose not to for golfing sake

Answer (score 1):

Don't understand why 0,4 is [6, 8]. Both 6 and 8 have already appeared in 0,2 : [6, 8, 9].

```
u = [];
$.each(x, function(i, arr){
    //console.log(arr);
    x[i] = $.grep(arr, function(elem, i){
        return ($.inArray(elem, u) == -1);
    });
    $.merge(u, arr);
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfJmd/)

Object x is modified with result of

0,2:    [6, 8, 9]
0,3:    [1](http://jsfiddle.net/NfJmd/)
0,4:    []
0,5:    []
0,6:    [4, 5]
0,7:    []
0,8:    [7]

```
$.each(x, function(i, arr){
    u = [];
    $.each(x, function(j, arrJ){
        $.merge(u, i == j ? [] : arrJ);
    });

    var ue = null;
    $.each(arr, function(i, elem){
        if ($.inArray(elem, u) == -1) {
            ue = elem;
        }
    });

    if (ue != null){
        arr.length = 0;
        arr[0] = ue;
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NfJmd/1)

Comment: how does this outputs an object which obeys the needed result's rules?

Comment: because the Value's (arrays) being modified are only the ones which has totally unique numbers across all the other arrays. no notice only 0,3 has the number "1" in it's Value's array, there for eliminating all the other numbers inside it. that is the rule of this conversion.

Comment: "Now, I want to narrow down my object to this, by checking if any number in an Array appears only inside this array, and not in others that are part of the object." - implies that any number within an array would be eliminated if it appears in any other array. I still don't get the logic for 0,4 is [6, 8]. May be you could explain little more. Make sure to update the question itself.

Comment: i wrote "...then eliminating all the other numbers inside the specific array which holds the unique number" so only elimination for arrays containing unique numbers

Comment: Now I see the updated requirements. I think I get it. I will update the logic in a few.

Comment: How does this play when the removed item cause another array to have an element that become unique across? One pass may not be sufficient to complete it. Are multiple passes allowed? I believe this is depicted in // now 4 becomes also a "loner". What happens then?

Comment: the only real need for jQuery here is the $.merge function, everything else can be done with normal javascript. if something can be done via JS I think it's best to not involve other libraries to do it.

Answer (score 1):

the idea is to use buckets,
consider this a fun experiment, and i know the code can be optimized, and not so pretty, but it solves the problem, and it's not that inefficient:

```
var x = {};  // object

x[[0,2]] = [6, 8, 9];
x[[0,3]] = [1, 6, 8];
x[[0,4]] = [6, 8];
x[[0,5]] = [6, 8];
x[[0,6]] = [4, 5, 8, 9];
x[[0,7]] = [5, 8];
x[[0,8]] = [4, 5, 7, 9];

var trackCount = [];

for(var key in x){
  for(var j in x[key]){
     // console.log(key);
          if(typeof(trackCount[x[key][j]]) === "undefined"){
       trackCount[x[key][j]] = [];
      }
     // trackCount[x[key][j]].push(trackCount[x[key]]);
       trackCount[x[key][j]].push(key);
  }
}
//console.log(trackCount)
for(var i=0;i<trackCount.length;++i){
   if(trackCount[i] && trackCount[i].length == 1){
     x[trackCount[i][0]] = [];
     x[trackCount[i][0]].push(i)
   }
}
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Long-winded Approach ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/HkxPF/3/))

```
var sudoku    =  { '0,2' : [6,8,9]
                 , '0,3' : [1,6,8]
                 , '0,4' : [6,8]
                 , '0,5' : [6,8]
                 , '0,6' : [4,5,8,9]
                 , '0,7' : [5,8]
                 , '0,8' : [4,5,7,9]
                 };

var finished  =  false;

while (!finished) {
    var unique  =  {};
    finished    =  true;

    // Build Unique Numbers List
    for (var section in sudoku)
        for (var pos = sudoku[section].length; pos--; ){
            if (typeof unique[ sudoku[section][pos] ] === "undefined")
                unique[ sudoku[section][pos] ] = [];

            unique[sudoku[section][pos]].push(section);
        }    

    // Clean Up Unique Numbers List
    for (var num in unique)
        if (unique[num].length > 1)
            delete unique[num];

    // Remove non-Uniques
    var is_unique = false;
    for ( var num in unique )
        for ( var pos = sudoku[ unique[num] ].length; pos--; ){
            is_unique = false;
            for (var unique_value in unique)
                if (sudoku[ unique[num] ][pos] == unique_value){
                    is_unique = true;
                    break;
                }

            if (!is_unique){
                sudoku[ unique[num] ].splice(pos,1);
                finished = false;
            }
        }
}

console.clear();
console.dir(unique);
console.dir(sudoku);
/**/
```

---

#### Result

{sudoku}
     [0,2]  :  [9]
     [0,3]  :  [1]
     [0,4]  :  [6, 8]
     [0,5]  :  [6, 8]
     [0,6]  :  [4]
     [0,7]  :  [5]
     [0,8]  :  [7]

---

**Note:** This is not the most optimized algorithm to use, but since this is for Sudoku, performance won't really be impacted by any algorithm you choose.  So, I'd choose amit_g's jQuery solution for conciseness.  Otherwise, the above should do well for both explanation and accuracy.

**Edit:** This has been modified to recursively filter the results.

Comment: your answer/solution is even more complicated than mine.. but I liked Avi Pinto's solution.

Comment: None of the solutions other than mine end up with the unique set that mine shows.  I will say that Avi and I had similar approaches.  If you think mine is complicated, then I advise you to give up programming.  This is almost as simplistic as it can get.  What may be confusing is using a reverse-for loop, which is used for performance, since it is comparable to a reverse-while.

Comment: I would recommend you re-reading this, since it is like Avi's solution, but includes a few more necessary steps and a few more optimizations, the main difference between ours seems to be the final for-loop.  The optimizations left to be made will consist of sorting the arrays and breaking out of the for-loops once you hit a number that's greater than the largest unique.

Comment: you have changed a bit the desired output so it would include a naked-pairs system, to eliminate all the `6` & `8` in the other cells' possibilities array.. that is something I also need, but it's considered a method by itself.. thanks for you're solution! it's very interesting to read!

Comment: I think it's still far more complicated than needed. check my solution, i've improved it

Comment: Yes, I was going on your `// now 4 becomes a loner` comment, which shows you wanted some recursion.  The main thing to take from this is that reverse-while's can't be implemented everywhere, due to the defined termination point (`0`), but here's is a great place where it can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a separate single dimension array that keeps track of the values in the multi-dimensional array.

Iterate through each value in the multi-dimensional array. If the value doesn't exist in the single-dimension array, add it to the single dimension array and keep it in the multi-dimension array.  If the value DOES exist in the single-dimension array, just remove it from the multi-dimension array and move on to the next value.

Comment: it won't work like that, it will remove more numbers than needed. i need to remove all the numbers in an array beside the one which is the unique one..